# Communication between VPC subnet instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ping, subnet, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to set up a very simple VPC environment, but I'm having troubles making the instances in the subnet see each others: ie, when I ping 10.0.0.10 from 10.0.0.93 it doesn't succeed.

I thought it was a problem belonging to some misconfiguration but, review everything I can't find the problem.

Here are my routes table (as default):

```
rtb-14f2127c, 1 Subnet, No, vpc-1ef21276 (10.0.0.0/16)
rtb-10f21278, 0 Subnets, Yes, vpc-1ef21276 (10.0.0.0/16)
```

Just one DHCP Option:

```
dopt-12f2127a    domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS;
```

My network ACL (inbound):

```
100 ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
*   ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0   DENY
```

(outbound):

```
100 ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
*   ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0   DENY
```

My security group has (inbound):

```
ALL sg-b3637adf 
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0   
4848    0.0.0.0/0   
8080 (HTTP*)    0.0.0.0/0   
8258    0.0.0.0/0   
24848   0.0.0.0/0   
28009   0.0.0.0/0   
28080   0.0.0.0/0   
28181   0.0.0.0/0
```

(outbound):

```
ALL 0.0.0.0/0
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0   
8080 (HTTP*)    0.0.0.0/0   
8258    0.0.0.0/0   
28009   0.0.0.0/0   
28080   0.0.0.0/0   
28181   0.0.0.0/0
```

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved the problem: I added at the security group (both in inbound and in outbound)

```
ALL sg-b3637adf
```

**And** I fixed a problem with the security group id (sg-b3637adf).

Doing these two steps made instances able to ping themselves.

For future readers, if you have a security group with ICMP ports blocked, you will not be able to ping. Make sure you have a rule in your security group to allow all ICMP access.

Comment: This also allows joining of boxes to domain within VPC. Just having TCP ports opened wont be enough to join a domain. fyi :) and thanks

Answer (score 5):

Also, I would like to add that for others running into similar issues: If you are setting up a VPC, you may want to turn off your instance specific iptables so that you can use the VPC specific firewall rules defined in the security groups!

Answer (score 2):

To make ping works between two instances, all ICMP ports should be opened between the instances. No need to open all ports between them.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that if review the routing tables for your machine, you may think it's not reflecting what is in the AWS VPC configuration - e.g. your VPC has a local route for 10.0.0.0/16, but your machine's routing table only has a local route for 10.0.0.0/24.

Don't be distracted by this red herring! It seems that the default route - even though it doesn't exist, and you might assume it's only the internet gateway - is where packets go before being manipulated by the VPC itself.